# QFileInfo and UTF-8

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having trouble getting QFileInfo to work with UTF-8 paths.
I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
While std::filesystem has no issue with the (in this case) German UTF-8, it seems QFileInfo is not using UTF-8, even though the Qt documentation says the default encoding is unicode (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html)

EDIT:
before the example with the file,here is a simpler example.
This example shows that QString is not the issue, but rather the settings that influence the Qt I/O:

```
QString temp {"Höhe.txt"};
qDebug()<<"Qt temp: "<<temp;
std::cout<<"Qt through std: "<<temp.toStdString()<<std::endl;
std::string str = temp.toStdString();
std::cout<<"std: "<<str<<std::endl;
```

results:

```
Qt temp:  "Hhe.txt"
Qt through std: Höhe.txt
std: Höhe.txt
```

So, qDebug() is omitting the 'Ö' while the QString::toStdString() delivers the full string correctly.

Here is a distilled example code:
In all cases below std::filesystem finds the file, but Qt doesn't see it.
The qDebug() output is always without the 'Ö' - it is simply 'Hhe.txt'
NOTE: my real code is not using string literals - the below string literal is only used for the example to keep things simple.

```
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::filesystem::path p{"Höhe.txt"};
    //QFileInfo f(p.c_str()); 
    //QFileInfo f(std::filesystem::u8path(p.c_str()).c_str());
    //QFileInfo f(QString::fromUtf8(std::filesystem::u8path(p.c_str()).c_str()));
    QByteArray encodedString = "Höhe.txt";
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    //QString file = codec->toUnicode(encodedString);
    QString file = QString::fromUtf8(encodedString);
    QFileInfo f(file);
    if(!std::filesystem::exists(p)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(!f.exists()) {
        qDebug()<<f.filePath(); //outputs 'Hhe.txt' for all cases
        return 1;
    }
    
   std::cout<<"found"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

Can anyone help me get QFileInfo to also be able to see files with unicode characters?

Many thanks in advance!

Some additional information (as per questions in the comments):

```
~$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=en:el
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

My system however generally, has no issue showing German text, be in console or UIs..

and

```
$ ls Höhe.txt | od -t c
0000000   c   h   i   n   e   s   e   .   e   x   t  \n   c   z   e   c
0000020   h   .   e   x   t  \n   d   u   t   c   h   .   e   x   t  \n
0000040   e   n   g   l   i   s   h   _   u   k   .   e   x   t  \n   f
0000060   i   n   n   i   s   h   .   e   x   t  \n   f   r   e   n   c
0000100   h   .   e   x   t  \n   g   e   r   m   a   n   .   e   x   t
0000120  \n   g   r   e   e   k   .   e   x   t  \n   i   t   a   l   i
0000140   a   n   .   e   x   t  \n   j   a   p   a   n   e   s   e   .
0000160   e   x   t  \n   p   o   l   i   s   h   .   e   x   t  \n   p
0000200   o   r   t   u   g   u   e   s   e   .   e   x   t  \n   s   p
0000220   a   n   i   s   h   .   e   x   t  \n   s   w   e   d   i   s
0000240   h   .   e   x   t  \n   t   u   r   k   i   s   h   .   e   x
0000260   t  \n
0000262
```

And:

```
main.cpp: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: Check the encoding for your source file.  Also you might need `u8"Höhe.txt"` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Maybe use [`QString::fromUtf8`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8)?

Comment: @RichardCritten the string literal here is just an example - my real code has no hard coded string literals, so u8"xxxx" is not applicable.

Comment: You still need a way to ensure the string encoding is really UTF-8.  With Linux there's a good chance it is, but you should look at the values of each byte to verify.  For instance the string you used in the question should start with 72 195 182 104 101.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the suggestions. I just tried QString::fromUtf8() same behaviour. I added it to the post.

Comment: Works for me. Type `locale` in your terminal, what do you get? Type `ls Höhe.txt | od -t c`, what do you get? Type `file yoursourcefile.cpp`, what do you get?

Comment: So is `Höhe.txt` a directory? Maybe type `ls -d Höhe.txt | od -t c` then.

Comment: Oh you have the `LANG` environment variable set to `C`. This breaks everything. Not sure how other programs that need Unicode ever manage to work. Reset to `en_US.UTF-8` and try again. Setting it to `C.UTF-8` or unsetting it altogether should also work (at least it works for me, as long as you have LC_ALL set to something reasonable).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. many thanks for your suggestions. I will try this on another system, as it seems like a system configuration rather than a code issue. Though changing LANG or unsetting it didn't change anything...

Comment: Try sending to `qDebug()` with `toStdString` as well and see if anything changes.

Comment: @MarkRansom qDebug() does not accept std::string

Comment: Maybe `toUtf8` instead, since that's what `toStdString` uses anyway.

Comment: "changing LANG or unsetting it didn't change anything" This is rather improbable. Show the exact commands you were running.

Answer (score 3):

The comments from n.m. were on the right track.
The issue is not in the code, as I originally thought but the locale configuration on my system.

The output of:

```
 QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->name().toStdString();
```

is `'System'`.
I am not sure what 'System' is configured to though.
And setting Qt Locale on UTF-8 explicitly:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Made the code work correctly on my system as well.
This means that the issue is in the Locale configuration of my system.
So I have to figure out what is wrong with my Locale, but that is a different question.

Many thanks to all of you who helped!!

Comment: I would expect "System" to be whatever your local system is set to use, but for Linux I'd expect it to be UTF-8 anyway!  Glad you found it.